# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81 using Selenium ChromeDriver v81

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I imported webdriver from selenium and os. I want to be able to run this piece of code successfully:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= os.path.abspath('') + '/chromedriver')
```

The error I'm getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
```

I'm using python 2.7 on a MAC OSX.
I have version 81.0.4044.138 of the chromedriver installed from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
in the same workspace directory, and it is named 'chromedriver', but it's like my webdriver doesn't recognize it. I would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Analysis

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *ChromeDriver 81.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver 81.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/81.0.4044.138/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 81**

Most probhably the *Chrome Browser* got updated to [**Chrome v83.0**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/nic83) as a part of the recent push.

- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v83.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 83**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *unknown* to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v81.0* and the *Chrome Browser v83.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v83.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 83.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v83.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening in most cases due to differences between the Chrome web driver version and the Chrome Browser version.

I would suggest you to do the following:
1- Take a backup of your work.
2- Update Chrome Browser to the latest version.
3- Install the latest version of the chrome browser.
4- Kill any chromedriver process that is running in the background.
5- Clean up your code and give it a try.