# Using selenium-chrome-driver 4.0.0-alpha-5 and I'm getting this error: "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81"

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the latest version of Chrome as of 5/26/2020: 83.0.4103.61 (64-bit)

I'm experimenting with Maven projects on Eclipse. Here's my POM.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ah</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumberParallel</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm using the latest version of the selenium-chrome-driver (4.0.0-alpha-5) yet I'm getting the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created:
>   **This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81**   (Driver
>   info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.69
>   (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}),platform=Windows
>   NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969692/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome/61978510#61978510) discussion as well.

Comment: That uses python and I'm using Java. Not to mention that I'm dealing with a maven project and using pom.xml to load my dependencies.

Comment: Irespective of _Java_ and _Python_, the error _This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81_ happens only due to version mismatch. Did you go through the discussion within the comments?

Comment: The error has been resolved